# ggplot2 Installation on R [32bit - 64 bit mismatch]

Tags: 64-bit, r

I am a beginner in R. I am able to install "tidyverse" and "rlang" but when I type in "library(ggplot2) and execute it, I get the following error,

> library(ggplot2)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
>    unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/welcome/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/colorspace/libs/x64/colorspace.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I downloaded 'Rtools' and installed it but still the same error.
I have a 64 bit operating system with x64-based processor. Windows 10 with R x64 3.6.1.
What I do i need to do to use 'ggplot2' on my system? Please advise.

thanks

Comment: Can you check if the `C:/Users/welcome/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/colorspace/libs/x64/colorspace.dll` Dynamic Link Library really exists at that Path and that it does not have a Zero Size? Can you imagine why this Path has Forward-Slashes (`/`) instead of Back-Slashes (`\ `) on a _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ Operating System? Also, I would reinstall this Static Software Application inside the `"C:\Program Files\"` Folder. The `C:\Users\ ` Folder should be kept for Non-Executable Files, as much as possible.

Comment: Dobrescu, Thanks for the reply.
 I checked. 'colorspace.dll' has a size of 56.5 kB. I followed the default file settings that was recommended by the system when I installed R. Should I have done anything differently? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, @Dan. I think that the Error Message is pretty straightforward: your existing and non-empty `x64/colorspace.dll` Dynamic Link Library is "_not a valid Win32 application_". Apparently, the `ggplot2` library is expecting to load a 32-Bit Static Software Application while you are feeding it a 64-Bit Static Software Application. Please update your Question in order to reflect the Version of your `R` Statistical Programming Language and its Bitness. Also, please add the `R` Tag to your Tag List. And seek an Expert in the `R` Statistical Programming Language.

Comment: will do. thank you.

Comment: Don't mention it. I have basically said only trivial stuff. Good luck in your quest.

Comment: You could still improve your Question by editing it in order to reflect the Version of your `Rtools` Library Package. Is it `3.6`?

Comment: Now I can see that they are _a lot of_ Static Software Applications. You could specify _exactly_ in your Question Body the Versions of the following Static Software Applications: _R Studio_ (x64 3.6.1?), _R Tools_, `tidyverse`, `rlang` and `ggplot2`. If you are combining Various Versions of these Software Packages and if some of them are 32-Bitty while others are 64-Bitty, then anything may happen.